# Conway's Game of Life FileIO

Tags: c, file-io

I'm working on learning C and decided to port my Game of Life code over from Java. It doesn't seem too difficult except that the FileIO part. My input file looks something like:

```
Beehive
5 6

------
--XX--
-X--X-
--XX--
------
```

Here's the pseduo-code of what I did in Java;

```
Scanner to open the file,
String line = file.nextLine(),
print the line,
get the second line
Trim and split the firstLine,
String[tokens[0]][tokens[1]],

while(line != NULL) -> string[row][col] = input.charAt(i);
close input,
return string[][]
```

This is what I have so far in C,

```
void fileIO() {
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    file = fopen("INPUT_FILE", "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open file!");
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != NULL ) {

    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here? Can anyone give me a pointer in which way to go from here?

Comment: Well i think `fgets` is like `String line = file.nextLine()` where `buffer` is now your `line` so, I guess according to your pseudo-code, you want to print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To print a line**: [puts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts)

```
puts(buffer);
```

Note that after `fgets`, `buffer` contains the newline character `\n`, which will be printed too. I guess you want this behavior (not sure how this works in Java).

---

**To trim and split a line**: [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

```
int height, width;
...
sscanf(buffer, "%d%d", &height, &width);
```

---

**To extract a character from a string** (instead of `input.charAt(i)`):

```
char c = buffer[i];
```

This is not file I/O; it's just the C syntax for getting a character from a string.

---

It seems that you have a function in Java that returns a 2-D array (of characters? of strings?), which is dynamically allocated. Java supports recording the width and height in the array object itself, while C doesn't support this. Instead of the 2-D array, you will have to use a `struct`:

```
struct MyDataFromFile
{
    int height, width;
    bool **data;
};
```

Such data structure is only one possible option; you could use different options:

- `bool[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH]` - convenient if there is maximum height and width
- `uint64_t *data` if you want to use 1 bit for storage, instead of 1 byte - this requires additional bit-fiddling